# Can shared.module.ts contain child modules that share components?

Tags: angular, module, angular-cli

Let's say my app structure is currently like this:

```
-app.module  
    -shared.module 
        -datepicker.module  
        -grid.module
```

DatepickerComponent is declared and exported by datepicker.module and its html selector is 'datepicker'.

GridComponent is declared in grid.module.

Both modules are imported by shared.module.

Is it possible for me to use DatepickerComponent inside GridComponent, not by importing it in the ts file, but by using its selector in grid.component.html?

For some reason this throws an error saying  is not a known element

Edit: I should add that the components inside datepicker.module and grid.module will be used across the whole app too. Would it be simpler to do away with the child modules completely and just import their components directly into shared.module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridComponent` is in its own module so it has no way to know about `DatepickerComponent` even if they are both imported in `SharedModule`.

> the components inside datepicker.module and grid.module will be used across the whole app too

I would definitely simply add them in `SharedModule`. I don't see the reason to create a module for each of those 2 components. If you have more requirements, please share them or update the question.

Comment: So Grid and Datepicker component wont know about each other even if i export both of them and additionally put their modules in SharedModule's exports array? I was only considering splitting up shared components into more modules for easier compartmentalization. But if it will cause problems then I will refrain from doing so, thanks.